# Windows Service read cmd lines with eventhandler

Tags: c#, windows, service, event-handling

I'm trying to run a command in the command prompt and run it as a service. This command starts the queue listener from Laravel. I want to run it as a service so this queue listener always runs in the background. When the listener outputs some lines I want to capture these and send an email. I already tried my code running it as a process and it's working, but when I try to run the code as a service it doesn't start.

```
    Process process();


    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C php artisan queue:listen --tries=3 --timeout=0 --memory=1024";
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:/xampp/htdocs/phpproject";

        process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(p_OutputDataReceived);
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }

    private void p_OutputDataReceived(object sendingProcess,
        DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
    {
        // Collect the command output.  
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data.ToString()))
        {
            sendMail(process.StandardOutput.ToString());
        }
    }
```

**Edit:**
When I comment the process.WaitForExit() line the service runs and the queue listener does its work!. 
But the next problem I have is the service never hits the eventhandler. It did when I was running it only as a process. Any clue why this isn't working as a service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this;

```
private Process process = null;
private DataReceivedEventHandler TheDataReceievedEventHandler;

private void startProcess()
{
    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"cmd.exe", @"/C php artisan queue:listen --tries=3 --timeout=0 --memory=1024")
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        WorkingDirectory = @"C:/xampp/htdocs/phpproject",
    };

    if ((process = Process.Start(processStartInfo)) != null)
    {
        process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        process.Exited += new EventHandler(ExitedHandler);

        TheDataReceievedEventHandler = new DataReceivedEventHandler(StandardOutputHandler);
        process.OutputDataReceived += TheDataReceievedEventHandler;
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.ErrorDataReceived += TheDataReceievedEventHandler;
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
    }
}

private void ExitedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException(); // the service you're trying to run closed it self.
}

private void StandardOutputHandler(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
}
```

The problem is if the service you are trying to run closes it self, it will stop outputting and the process will be closed. Similar to CMD behavior each time you send a command to CMD it will close it self after you receive the error or output.

So if for example; I want to use CMD to see my task-list, i will have to build a loop were i run a CMD process on a regular interval because after each command it will close it self.

## Edit

If you can't stop the program using its own logic you will need to kill the process of the program itself. You can do that using the following code;

```
try // If you have no administrator privilege, try will fire.
{
    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName("name process")) // You can get the name by looking in your task manager.
            {
                proc.Kill();
            }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // Add error handling
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Immediately solved my problem!

Comment: What's the best way to kill the process? When I do a process.kill() the process is still running in the background.

Comment: @FelixNotermans Dus php artisan have a command that makes it shut down when your using it in CMD if not you will have to kill the process programmatically.

Comment: No, when I want to exit it in a cmd window I just hit control + c

Comment: @FelixNotermans I edited my answer hope this helps and give you a general idea of what to do.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't help. I can access and end the process by process.kill. I don't think there's any need to search for it by name. Somehow the process is succesfully killed but the php artisan command is still running in the background. When I rightclick on the service when it's running in the taskmanager and click on go to process, it doesn't show me a process.

Comment: @FelixNotermans Your suppose to kill artisan using that code not the process of your program, that just starts artisan and monitors it. That will close on it's own once artisan is killed.